# How to prevent losing data when navigating in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to store array of items in a service (called cart service) and show it in component (cart.component.ts).
but the items are chosen each alone by the component bgview.component.ts that is a children of component single.component.ts that receive the items through http requests.

when i open the cart component i receive an empty array.
can i store these items in the service without losing them when navigating.

i've tried the following steps:

The component that i want to send items from :

```
export class BgviewComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() item: Item;
  constructor(private cartservice: CartService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onAddToCart(){
    this.cartservice.items.push(this.item);


  }
}
```

the service :

```
   @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
  })
export class CartService {
public items: Item[]=[];

}
```

the receiving component:

```
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
 items: Item[]=[];

  constructor(private cartservice:CartService) { 


  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = this.cartservice.items;
    console.log(this.items) //gives empty array

  }

}
```

routing way:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeModule } from './pages/home/home.module';
import { ContactusModule } from './pages/contactus/contactus.module';
import { SingleModule } from './pages/single/single.module';
import { LoginModule } from './pages/login/login.module';
import { SearchpModule } from './pages/searchp/searchp.module';
import { AdminModule } from './pages/admin/admin.module';
import { FindpModule } from './pages/findp/findp.module';
import { AuthGuardService } from './services/auth.service';
import { CartModule } from './pages/cart/cart.module';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => HomeModule,
  },
  {
    path: 'contact',
    loadChildren: () => ContactusModule,
  },
  {
    path: 'single/:id',
    loadChildren: () => SingleModule,
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => LoginModule,
  },
  {
    path: 'searchp/:id',
    loadChildren: () => SearchpModule,
  },
  {
    path: 'login/admin',
    loadChildren: () => AdminModule,  canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: 'cart',
    loadChildren: () => CartModule,
  },
  {
    path: 'findp/:str',
    loadChildren: () => FindpModule,
  },
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

cart module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CartComponent } from './cart.component';
import { CartRoutingModule } from './cart-routing.module';
import { CartService } from 'src/app/services/cart.service';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [ CartComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CartRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers:[

  ]
})
export class CartModule { }
```

single module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SingleComponent } from './single.component';
import { SharedModule } from 'src/app/shared/shared.module';
import { SingleRoutingModule } from './single-routing.module';
import { BgviewComponent } from './bgview/bgview.component';
import { HttpService } from 'src/app/services/http.service';
import { CartService } from 'src/app/services/cart.service';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [SingleComponent, BgviewComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    SingleRoutingModule,

  ],
  providers:[
    HttpService,

  ]
})
export class SingleModule { }
```

please help me i'm stuck here.

Comment: Did you inject service using provider? Can you show us component definition of cart.component.ts and single.component.ts

Comment: @Kenny done i've showed them all

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that `onAddToCart` method is called.
You can simply add some log message inside method to check it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the onAddToCArt method is called.